# How many daughters prophet Muhammad S.A.W.W have?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, children

I have read `Sunni` as well as `Shia` books for the reference and confused that how many daughters our prophet actually have?

If have four daughters as per Hadith then it raise following points.

1. Why did Holy Prophet PBUH took only one daughter in `Mubahila` event against christians while `Allah` ask in a plural way.
   `Come lets bring your sons and our sons, your females and our females.`
2. Why only one daughter is the leader of all females in heaven? Isn't it injustice with other daughters and Prophet can never do injustice.
3. Why only one daughter's children called `Aulad e Rasool`?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. These are three different questions you should ask them separately. And as for the 3rd statement I'd ask you for an evidence for saying so, as I've never heard of it!

Comment: Were the other daughters alive at the time of Mubahila?

Comment: @Uma they weren't it is also unclear whether or not Ibrahim was alive, and even if he was he was a baby and wouldn't take part of the Mubahala الْمُبَاهَلَة.

Comment: @Uma two of the daughters were alive on Fatah Makka and There are only two Quarnic verse revealed after Fatah Makka. It means Muhabila Happened before Fatah Makka and before the death of Hazrat Zainab (8-Hijri) & Umme Kulthoom (9-Hijri).

Comment: Usamah ibn Zayd narrated:

I went to the Prophet (S) one night about something I required and he came out with something (I did not know what) under his cloak. When I had finished telling him my business I asked him what he had under his cloak, and when he opened it I saw al-Hasan and al-Husayn on his laps. He then said, "These are my sons and my daughter’s sons. O Allah, I love them, so I beseech Thee to love them and those who love them.”
- Sahih Tirmidhi, per:
- Mishkat al-Masabih, English Version, Tdadition #6156

@Medi1Saif i think its enough reference for "Aulad e Rasool"

Comment: As Ibrahim (A.S) wasn't there it means either he wasn't alive or he wasn't born yet.  Because if he was alive there is no reason to leave him behind as Allah Order.
`Ask them to bring your sons & our sons` So Holy prophet should take his own direct son if he was alive there.

Comment: @SyedQamarAbbas I don't know what to make of your claims, AFAIK much of Surah Taubah was revealed after the conquest of Makkah. Mubahalah took place in 9-10 AH when the delegation from Najran came.

Comment: Ibrahim was the son of Muhammed and Maria the Copthic he died as a child. And your claim that after Fath Mecca there were only two revelations is hardly true as between Fath Mekka and the death of the prophet is a time difference of many years and the revelation didn't stop until short before the prophet's death.

Answer (score 2):

The Prophet had four daughters.

---

```
Why did Holy Prophet PBUH took only one daughter in Mubahila event 
against christians while  Allah ask in a plural way. Come lets bring your 
sons and our sons, your females and our females.
```

The verse of Mubahalah was revealed when a delegation from Najran met the Prophet and disputed with him about Isa عليه السلام.

> قال ابن عباس : هم أهل نجران : السيد والعاقب وابن الحارث رؤساؤهم
>
> Ibn Abbas said: They are the people of Najran : Saeed, Aqib and Ibn Harith were their leaders
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Qurtuby](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura3-aya61.html#qortobi)</sup>

> قال: نـزلت في العاقب والسيد من أهل نجران، وهما نصرانيان
>
> He said: This was revealed regarding Aqib and Saeed who were from the people of Najran, and they were Christians
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Tabary](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/tabary/sura3-aya59.html#tabary)</sup>

The delegation came in 10 AH:

> وفيها قدم وفد العاقب والسيد من نجران
>
> This year came the delegation of Aqib and Saeed from Najran
>
> <sup>— [Tarikh Tabari ; سنه عشر (Tenth Year of Hijrah)](https://al-maktaba.org/book/9783/1414#p5)</sup>

None of the other daughters of the Prophet, other than Fatimah, were alive at this time.

- Zainab had died in 8 AH:

  > فَفِيهَا تُوُفِّيَتْ- فِيمَا زَعَمَ الْوَاقِدِيُّ- زَيْنَبُ ابْنَةُ رَسُولِ الله ص
  >
  > This year died: Zainab the daughter of the Messenger of Allah ﷺ
  >
  > <sup>— [Tarikh al-Tabari ; سنه ثمان من الهجره (Year Eight of Hijrah)](https://al-maktaba.org/book/9783/1302#p3)</sup>
- Ruqayyah had died in 2 AH:

  > قَالَ أُسَامَةُ بْنُ زَيْدٍ: فَأَتَانَا الْخَبَرُ حِينَ سَوَّيْنَا التُّرَابَ عَلَى رُقَيَّةَ بِنْتِ رسول الله ص الَّتِي كَانَتْ عِنْدَ عُثْمَانَ بْنِ عَفَّانَ، كَانَ رسول الله ص خَلَّفَنِي عَلَيْهَا مَعَ عُثْمَانَ
  >
  > Osama bin Zaid said: When we received the news [of the victory at Badr] we were burying Ruqayyah the daughter of the Messenger of Allah ﷺ. She was married to Uthman bin Affan and the Messenger of Allah had left behind Uthman and me to care for her.
  >
  > <sup>— [Tarikh al-Tabari ;  السنه الثانيه من الهجره (Second Year of Hijrah)](https://al-maktaba.org/book/9783/1084#p5)</sup>
- Umm Kulthum had died in 9 AH:

  > وَفِي هَذِهِ السَّنَةِ ماتت أم كلثوم ابنه رسول الله ص فِي شَعْبَانَ
  >
  > In this year died Umm Kulthum, the daughter of the Messenger of Allah ﷺ  in the month of Sha'ban
  >
  > <sup>— [Tarikh al-Tabari ; سنه تسع (Year Nine)](https://al-maktaba.org/book/9783/1399#p2)</sup>

---

```
Why only one daughter is the leader of all females in heaven? Isn't it 
injustice with other daughters and Prophet can never do injustice.
```

I don't understand your logic here. Why do all the daughters need to be equal in their excellence and virtue? Is not Yusuf  عليه السلام of a higher rank to his brothers, despite them all being the sons of Yaqub  عليه السلام?

Comment: What about the Leadership of women in Jannah?
Why only one daughter of Holy Prophet is the leader of all women in Jannah and thats only Hazrat Fatima S.A. even if other daughters have been passed away they could be made "Syeda tul Nasaa il Alameen" But Holy Prophet only made one daughter. Our Prophet never do injustice with anyone then why such a great injustice with his own daughters?

Comment: @SyedQamarAbbas I've already answered this. Why are Hassan and Hussain the leaders of the youth of paradise when Qasim, Abdullah and Ibrahim are the Prophet's direct sons?

Comment: I am asking about Fatima Zahra. Not Hassan and Hussain. They are separate case than Fatima. Because Hassan and Hussain both are not direct sons. But Fatima is direct daughter just like others as per your Answer.

Comment: @SyedQamarAbbas And I am using your own logic against you, isn't it injustice to Ibrahim ,Qasim and Abdullah that they are not made leaders when they are sons of the Prophet? Grandsons are also sons.

Comment: Because they die in such a young age and at this age no one can be rewarded on the base of Taqwa because wrong doing/right doing decisions starts fro puberty since none of they reached at the age of puberty.

Comment: @SyedQamarAbbas According to your own logic their relative virtue doesn't matter, they were sons of the Prophet so it is injustice to not make them equal rank to Hassan and Hussain. If virtue does matter then we agree that Fatimah's rank is above her sisters.

Comment: Don't you think Hassan and Hussain are Muhammad's son? As per Mubahila's ayat both Hassan and Hussain are son of Prophet.

Comment: @SyedQamarAbbas Yes I do say that they are Muhammad's ﷺ sons. That is exactly what I am trying to say to you. I am using your own logic on the sons rather than the daughters.

Comment: Hassan and Hussain are son's more value-able and close to Prophet than his own sons Because of Fatima.
Holy Prophet reward every thing to Fatima.
Fadak, Leadership, Ahl ul bait, Alway stand when ever she came. Every reward is for fatima but not for other daughters? Why is that so?

Comment: If for once i believe your logic. Prophet give leadership to Fatima on the base of Taqwa and Maqaam. But doesn't including other daughters in Ahl-ul-Bait `People of Household`. I don't think for being a household of Prophet other daughters need  any special qualities?

Comment: @SyedQamarAbbas You are now going on a tangent and raising a different point than in your question, so this is offtopic discussion. Sunnis believe even the Prophet's wives to be part of the Ahl-ul-Bait based on [11:73](http://quran.com/11/73), so yes the other daughters are also part of them.

Comment: How can you believe? Haven't you read the `Hadith e Kisa`? Ayesha was the narrater and she it self doesn't count her from ahl ul bait. Please read this Hadith from Sahih Bukhari.

Comment: This is a chaining question.

Comment: I have already said how I can believe that ... because the Quran says so. If you disagree then you are free to believe what you want, I have no desire to engage in Shia-Sunni debates and you are going beyond the focus of the question.