# How many children did prophet Muhammad have?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, seerah

Assalamualaikum, I'm actually confused, I have found in Internet that prophet had 6 children (4 daughters and 2 sons),another place it say he had actually 7 children(4 daughters and 3 sons],which one is correct,or how many children he had?

Comment: Related question [How many daughters prropeht Muhammad saww have?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49973/how-many-daughters-prophet-muhammad-s-a-w-w-have)

Answer (score 1):

The sons of the Prophet ﷺ died in infancy. Apart from Ibrahim the other sons were born and died in the very early Meccan period. Hence information about their exact number is not certain and there are around 5 different claims in this regard.

According to the report which is preferred by some scholars the Prophet ﷺ had three sons : Qasim, Abdullah and Ibrahim. Some sources have named additional sons: Tahir, Mutahir, Tayyab, Mutayyab - however some have claimed that these were just alternate names.

The Prophet ﷺ had four daughters: Zaynab, Ruqayyah, Umm Kulthum and Fatimah.

All of his children apart from Ibrahim were born in the Meccan period from his wife Khadijah. While Ibrahim was born in Medinah from his concubine Mariah the Copt.

---

**Ref:**

> ما كان محمد أبا أحد من رجالكم
>
> Muhammad is not the father of [any] one of your men
>
> <sup>— [Quran 33:40](https://quran.com/33/40?translations=20)
> which means that none of his sons grew to be (adult) men.</sup>

[Al-Bidaya wa'l-Nihaya](https://shamela.ws/book/4445/4376): ذكر أولاده عليه وعليهم الصلاة والسلام

https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/23294/